# Can I get the value of home page component like custom link in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, home-page-component, custom-link

I want to add values of Home Page's Standard Components like Custom Links on Custom VisualForce Page. Does anyone knows how can I do that? Does anyone knows where its values get stored? Tried workbench to get the values captured but couldn't find them

[image: Custom Links]

Answer (score 0):

The easy part is getting the links themselves.  You can easily run the following SOQL:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Url, LinkType, OpenType, 
       MasterLabel, Description
FROM WebLink
WHERE PageOrSObjectType = 'CustomPageItem'
```

However, that only gets you the links and URLs.  I don't think there's a way to get the Home Page Layouts themselves.  I wish I knew how.